# Edit form validation with Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC and Spring form validation in my project.
There is class named `Group` in object model and I created form for editing it.

**Form**

```
<spring:url var="saveGroup" value="/teacher/groups/save"/>
<form:form action="${saveGroup}" method="post" modelAttribute="group">

    <form:hidden path="id"/>

    <div id="nameDiv" class="control-group">
        <form:label path="title">Title:</form:label>
        <form:input path="title"/>
        <form:errors path="title"/>
    </div>

    <div id="specDiv" class="control-group">
        <form:label path="title">Specialty:</form:label>
        <form:select path="specialty">
            <form:options items="${specialties}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="title"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <spring:url var="groups" value="/teacher/groups"/>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        <a class="btn" href="${groups}"> Cancel </a>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/teacher/groups")
public class GroupsController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;
    @Autowired
    private SpecialtyService specialtyService;

    @ModelAttribute("group")
    public Group setGroup(Long id) {
        if (id != null) {
            return groupService.read(id);
        } else {
            return new Group();
        }
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Specialty.class, "specialty", 
            new SpecialtyEditor(specialtyService));
        binder.setValidator(new GroupValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView groups() {
        return new ModelAndView("teacher/groups/list", "groups", 
            groupService.list());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit")
    public ModelAndView editGroup() {
        return new ModelAndView("teacher/groups/edit", "specialties",
            specialtyService.list());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveGroup(@Valid Group group, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "forward:/teacher/groups/edit";
        }
        groupService.update(group);
        return "redirect:/teacher/groups";
    }
}
```

I want to set the adequate behavior of my form in the case of failed validation. I.e. it should save its state but only show validation error message (as when using javascript to validate).
I thought that "forward:/teacher/groups/edit" will again forward request to `editGroup()` with saved objects `group` and `result`. But when I failed validation form just reloads and show start state of edited `group`: no errors and no saved changes.
How can I do that correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by not forwarding request to other method but sending answer to user immediately. Now it works and looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveGroup(@Valid Group group, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/teacher/groups/edit", "specialties", specialtyService.list());
    }
    groupService.update(group);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/teacher/groups");
}
```